# Question about Generalized Cantor Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to understand a proof by contradiction for Cantor's Theorem starting with a small finite set and its power set.

So, suppose set $A = \{1\}$. Then $2^A = \{ \emptyset, \{1\}\}$

I want to show that a bijection is not possible between $A$ and $2^A$ in order to prove that the power set, $2^A$ has a strictly greater cardinality than $A$.

Suppose $f$ is a mapping from $A$ to $2^A$, then for $a \in A, f(a)$ is a subset of $A$. I want to show that such a mapping does not cover certain sets in $2^A$. Of course, it is trivial to show this for these smaller sets, but I chose the smaller set to see if I can better trace the logic that is used in the generalized proof.

We want to find a set $B$ such that $B$ is not in the image of $f$.

Let $B = \{a \in A : a \not\in f(a)\}$.

So, if $B = f(x)$ some $x \in A$. Is $x \in B$?

If $x \in B$, then by definition $x \not\in f(x)$. Since $B = f(x)$, $x\not\in B$, a contradiction.

But then $x \not\in B \implies x \not\in f(x)$ meaning that $x \in B$ by definition, another contradiction.

Thus, $B$ is not $f(x)$ for any $x \in A$.

Following the above logic:

Put $B = f(1)$. Is $1 \in B?$

If $1 \in B$, then $1 \not\in f(1)$. But then $1 \not\in B$, a contradiction.

But if $1 \not\in B$, then $1 \not\in f(1)$, which means $1 \in B$ another contradiction.

I am trying to see how and if this translates to the more intuitive idea that once you map $1$ to either $\emptyset$ or $\{1\}$, you have a subset in the power set $2^A$ that is not mapped to any element in $A$.

Comment: I might be missing it, but what is your question?

Comment: So, I am having a bit of trouble making things more explicit. For instance, let's say I choose $1 \in B$, then that means $B = {1}$ since $1$ is an element in $B$. Then I find that $1 \not\in f(1) = B$ from the definition? It feels bizarre that I defined a function that contradicts itself, wouldn't this function also contradict itself if I was trying to find a bijection from :→?

Comment: @Vsotvep So for instance, I assume a bijection $f$ from $\{1\} \rightarrow \{1\}$, then I construct $B$ with the same definition as in the question then don't I also reach a contradiction and the incorrect conclusion that there is no bijection $f$ from $\{1\} \rightarrow \{1\}$?

Comment: You don't choose what is in $B$, the elements of $B$ are *defined* by the potential bijection $f$.

Comment: With $f:\{1\}\to\{1\}$ you don't reach a contradiction, since $B$ does not have to be in the image of $f$. In Cantor's theorem, you get a contradiction by using the fact that $B\subseteq A$ and that $f$ is a bijection between $A$ and $\mathcal P(A)$: this implies that $B=f(x)$ for some $x\in A$.

Comment: It is a generalized diagonal argument,